# Display endless amount of data in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I have an endless amount of data, can I display all of it in sql?
I know there is obviously select *, but then it will never complete.
Is there a command for this?

Comment: You can’t *display* all of it if it’s endless. :|

Comment: Your question is **extremely** unclear.  SQL cannot have an endless amount of data in the first place.

Comment: @SLaks.. this is what i was asked in an interview... i thought maybe there is something i am not familiar with

Comment: every question asked in interview does not be necessarily technically valid , some incorrect questions are deliberately asked to check your confidence level , test your temperament.

Comment: Not to mention that all being tasked with conducting an interview does not necessarily mean you are qualified to conduct one.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use TOP to select subset of total records

```
SELECT TOP 100 * from table
```

This selects top 100 records.

By using Order By clause , you can specify the basis on which subset of records is returned.

Now if you are asking about limits of Sql Server database management system then please see this [link - Maximum Capacity Specification of Sql Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

Eg

Max Databases per instance of SQL Server ( both 32 bit and 64 bit ) = 32,767

Comment: yup, but this will show only the top 100, not all.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you will prefer to use some kind of paging, since you cannot actually show "endless amount of data" in user-friendly way on application.